# Re size two views (expand / collapse)

Tags: android, animation, layout, android-animation

I have two views (fragments) in vertical linearlayout like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Im trying to expand the mapFragment to take whole space. Push the listFragment nicely down and in same time expand the mapFragment.

Im struggling how to do that with nice animation?

Overall is it too heavy operation to resize map control?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented example to this with two imageViews instead of FragmentLayout. It is collapsing and expanding just like the way you wanted. There are two buttons to expand and collapse.

These are my java class,xml and animations.

**java class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class expandAndCollapes extends Activity{


    boolean isExpanded=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.extend_lay);

        Button expand=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button collapse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


        final ImageView image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final ImageView image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        expand.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isExpanded){
                    image1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_out));
                    image2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down));
                    isExpanded=true;
                }

            }
        });

        collapse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(isExpanded){
                    image1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_in));
                    image2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up));
                    isExpanded=false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="expand" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="collapse" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**scale_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">


    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="4" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

**scale_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">


    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

**slide_down.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

**slide up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

</set>
```

What I did there is scale the first view 1 to 4 and slide down the second view.
It should be 4 specially because your layout weights are 1 and 3 (1+3=4). Hope this helps to you to get some idea.

Comment: This works but the upper view (in my case mapFragment) is stretched. So the map is not actually resized, it is stretched.